# Let's design a paper flyer for promoting Mi Yodeya!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, design, advertising

Now that we have a name and a logo, we can make promotional materials featuring our identity to help people spread awareness of Mi Yodeya to new audiences.

Let's design a paper flyer (presumably, but not necessarily 8.5" X 11") that people can print out and hang on bulletin boards in the synagogues, community centers, schools, Hillels, etc.

Please post answers consisting of one of:

- The text of what would go in the flyer plus description of graphical elements.
- A rough sketch of what the flyer would look like.
- A fully-developed flyer design.

If we agree on a design concept that's not fully-developed, someone in the community can complete the design, or we can ask Jin if he can.

If you just have partial concept ideas, please post them as comments.

There doesn't necessarily have to be only one final choice. For example, we may want to have one that's better for contexts in which more jargon is appropriate, and one that's all in English.

Comment: Perhaps we want one [all in Hebrew](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/why-judaism-stackexchange-com-how-come-not-yahadut-stackexchange-com#comment3139_1197) as well.

Comment: @DoubleAA, It's an interesting idea, but given that (at least for now), you need to be able to read English to understand any content on the site, I don't think it makes sense to try specifically to attract non-English-readers.

Comment: I think a magnet would be cool too. People tend to keep them around if they look respectable enough and don't take up too much space.

Comment: @WAF initial draft: http://i.imgur.com/rJzgw.png

Comment: Wouldn't A5 or DL be a better shape for a flyer?